# AADL with oData V4 client generator

Tags: c#, azure, odata, odata-v4

I'm trying to use Azure Active Diretory Library to implement authentication between a Web Application and a OData V4 WebApi. I using SQL to authenticate the user so, I don't need to authenticate the them using AADL, just authenticate the application. I saw several demos in the internet but none of them do this kind of thing. The major problem is my Web Application is using OData client Generator so I don't need open HttpClient request to call my API I just use the context to do it. Considering this scenario how can I protect my odata api to be use only by my web application? here's some examples of my code.

One of my odata controllers

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData;
using VPNUX.Model;

namespace VPNUX.API.Controllers
{

  public class EstadosController : ODataController
  {
    private readonly DB_VPNUX _db = new DB_VPNUX();

    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult GetEstados()
    {
        return Ok(_db.ESTADOS);
    }
  }
}
```

this is the way that I call this controller in my web application

```
public ApiContext ApiContext = new ApiContext(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"]));

_consultaViewData.PacienteViewData.Estados =
            ApiContext.Estados
                .Select(estado => new ListItem(estado.NOME, estado.ID))
                .ToList();
```

And everything comes directly from my OData Client .cs file

This is the first time that I'm using odata which works great but I need to protect my API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use basic authentication in OData Client, you can set credential in DataServiceContext by

```
var serviceCreds = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "SecurePassword"); 
var cache = new CredentialCache(); 
var serviceUri = new Uri("http://localhost/SimpleService"); 
cache.Add(serviceUri, "Basic", serviceCreds); 
ApiContext.Credentials = cache;
```

, Or you can set headers by using DataServiceContext.SendingRequest2.

```
ApiContext.SendingRequest2 += (sender, arg) =>
    {
        arg.RequestMessage.SetHeader("HeaderName", "HeaderValue");
    };
```